# php functions on right track?

Tags: php, function

I am tired of having 50 php pages, so I was thinking to collect some of them in some functions. I am trying to play a little bit around with it, but it is totally wrong what I am doing?

I have another php page where I have three forms. In these forms I can add a building, appartment  and people. The forms calls 3 different pages, and I would like to put them together in 1 php document with functions.

So how do I use functions? Is it correct that I put my insert statement in these functions?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// Selecting Database
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

function building() {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO renters (building) VALUES (?)");
}

function appartment() {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO renters (appartment) VALUES (?)");
}

function people() {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO renters (people) VALUES (?)");
}



                    // execute prepared statement 
                if ($stmt->execute()) { // tjek om udført:
                    $success = true;
                }
                    // luk statement
                $stmt->close();

                // luk connection
                $mysqli->close();         

if($success) {
    echo "Insert Succesfull";
} else {
    echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. It does not say what you are trying to do here exactly. The code is neither right now wrong since you haven't mentioned what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This is better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's a broad question. =) I think you should spend some time looking into a more object oriented approach. You'll find yourself with better structure and potentially a lot better overview of your code. There's a bunch of intros out there, but here are three I found valuable:

- [Object-Oriented PHP for Beginners](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762)
- [Basic concepts around Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.startutorial.com/homes/oo_beginner)
- [Object Oriented Programming for Absolute Beginners](http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/03/30/php-object-oriented-programming-for-absolute-beginners/)

Comment: Ok thank you I will look at that